# Ajax not triggering the success function. Laravel

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel, ajaxform

I am submitting a form and AJAX is displaying errors as it should but when everything goes right, it means that when form values are saving in database correctly AJAX is not triggering the success function.

**Here's the Laravel product verification code:**

```
 public function productVerify(Request $request)
    {

            $val =  $request->validate
            (
                [
                    'name' => 'required',
                    's_description' => 'required',
                    'l_description' => 'required',
                    'image_src' => 'required|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg',
                    'category' => 'required',
                    'quantity' => 'required|integer|not_in:0|regex:^[1-9][0-9]+^',
                    'price' => 'required|integer|not_in:0|regex:^[1-9][0-9]+^',
                ],
    
                [
                    'required' => 'The :attribute field is required',
                    'mimes' => 'Image should be a JPG, JPEG, or PNG',
                    'integer' =>  'The :attribute field should be an integer.', 
                    's_descripton.required' => 'The short description is required',
                    'l_descripton.required' => 'The long description is required',
                    'image_src.required' => 'The image file is required.'
                ]
            );

        
        
           
                if (!$val)
                {
                    return response()->json(['errors']);
                }
                else
                {
                    return response()->json(['success' => 'Product Added Successfully']);
                }
                
            
            
    }
```

**Here's the AJAX code:**

```js
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
       $("#addForm").submit(function(event)
       {
           
           // Store all data from form as object;
           var formData = new FormData(this);

           $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: 
                {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
        
           // AJAX implementation error:function() return errors without page reload.
           $.ajax(
           {
             url: '/save_product',
             type: "POST",
             processData:false,  
             contentType:false,
             cache:false,
             dataType: 'json',
             data:formData,

             success: function(xhr)
             {

                responseSu = xhr.responseJSON.success;
                alert(responseSu);
       
             },
            
             
             error:function(xhr, status, error) 
                 {

                    // Errors from the XML Http Request JSON Response

                        responseER = xhr.responseJSON.errors;

                    //  console.log(responseER);

                     $("#error").html(" ");

                     // For Each loop for printing errors from the response 

                     $.each(responseER, function (key, item) 
                     {
                        console.log(item);
                        $("#error").append("<li class='text-danger'>"+item+"</li>")
                        
                       // Hide Errors after 15 seconds with a fadeout animation

                        $("#error").show().delay(15000).fadeOut();
                       
                       
                        
                     });
                  
                     
                }
                
                 
           });  
           // Stop form from submitting normally
           event.preventDefault();
         
       });
       
       
   });
```

**After the form is submitted successfully and data is inserted into database it gives the error:**
[image: Console Error]

Comment: The stack trace on that error implies that it's triggering the `error` handler, not the `success` handler.  Which implies that there was an error.  In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, what is the actual response from the server?

Comment: @David The response is empty.

Comment: And what is the HTTP status code of the response?  An empty response body would certainly explain why `xhr.responseJSON` is `undefined`.  It would appear that the server is returning an error but isn't including much information about that error, so the client-side code shouldn't assume that information will always be there.

Comment: In Headers section Status Code: 200 OK.

Comment: That's inconsistent with what's shown in the question then.  It sounds like a mistake may be made during debugging.  Use your browser's script debugger and place a breakpoint (or a `debugger;` statement) on the very first line of both the `success` and the `error` callback functions.  When you reproduce the error in your test, which of the two is invoked and which exact line produces the error?

Comment: Add a `console.log(error);` statement to your `ajax` `error` handler and let us know what the console output is.